# Hadoop Hive keeps freezing when I run a create request with multiple objects

Tags: hadoop, hive, reduce

My Hive works when i do some simple table creates, but when i try to run any create table with a number of objects it freezes right after providing me the following,

```
Query ID = root_20160321031616_6fbfd536-f3e5-4517-ab8b-2dc8ddb34b85

Total jobs = 3

Launching Job 1 out of 3

Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

Starting Job = job_1458530057671_0001, Tracking URL = http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1458530057671_0001/

Kill Command = /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1458530057671_0001
```

I don't remember if "...no reduce operator" was present before when it worked.

The code I am trying to run is relatively straightforward,

```
create table BMO_F069_table as
select
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.text') as text,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id') as in_reply_to_user_id,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.id') as id,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.favorite_count') as favorite_count,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.coordinates') as coordinates,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.id_str') as id_str,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.user.location') as location,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.lang') as lang,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.indices') as indices,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.type') as type,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.hashtags') as hashtags,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.user_mentions') as user_mentions,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.user.screen_name') as screen_name,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.user.name') as name,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.in_reply_to_screen_name') as in_reply_to_screen_name,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.retweet_count') as retweet_count,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.favorited') as favorited,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.retweeted_status') as retweeted_status,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.user') as user,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.followers_count') as followers_count,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.statuses_count') as statuses_count,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.description') as description,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.geo_enabled') as geo_enabled,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.favourites_count') as favourites_count,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.created_at') as created_at,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.time_zone') as time_zone,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.listed_count') as listed_count,
    get_json_object(BMO_F069.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id_str') as in_reply_to_user_id_str
from BMO_F069;
```

The data consists of 60 MB of data.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about clusters to give you the specs.  Sorry.  But I do appreciate the feedback as well.  Thanks,
I had run similar queries hundreds of times in the last few weeks with data as big as half a terabyte with no issues.  When it froze up between a job, it stopped working for any new submissions.  Is there any way to reset it?

When i run Hive from Terminal, i get the following opening lines.  Is this normal?  I don't recall what the message was before.

```
16/03/21 21:16:55 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.optimize.mapjoin.mapreduce does not exist
16/03/21 21:16:55 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.heapsize does not exist
16/03/21 21:16:55 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
16/03/21 21:16:55 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask does not exist
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have run a similar job on my laptop and i get all the above information so I have confirmed that the above aren't error messages.
The process gets stuck right at the above stage but then the following does not sow up..
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers:0.... Perhaps the mappers aren't kicking in.. and if so, is there a way to reinitialize it?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a super unoptimized job, Hive will still try to finish its task, no matter how long it takes.

Since you didn't provide any useful information on cluster specs, data volumes and your query,... My guess it that either your query is not well written or you lack the cluster resources to timely finish your request.

Comment: You are right... i had run a huge unoptimized job.  That is when it froze.  But even though i've shut down everything, including my computer, Hadoop refuses to create the above table.  It will create a simple one line table, but won't do the above job.  I'm wondering if my node decided to turn itself off.  The information the terminal provides is that no reducer is available.  Do i need to restart something to get it back in working order?